# Android multicast.receive() dying and no exception

Tags: java, android

I am making a multicast messenger for part of my masters degree. I have previously successfully made this exact same implementation on desktop Java and had no issues what so ever. HOWEVER, when I run the code from Android problems occur. I can send to the multicast group just fine, but receiving does not work.

The output simply stops in the console after "2".

The application just stops giving me feedback on the line that is `socket.receive()`I am getting no exceptions either.

Below I have attached the class that I am using to receive the messages.
For the full android implementation I have the dropbox link available at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuoifbxqk01c079/MyApplication.zip?dl=0
It is pretty rough, but it does successfully send, just not receive.

```
 public class EMMS extends Thread{
            MulticastSocket socket;
            InetAddress ip;
            byte [ ] buffer;
            int usedPort;
            public boolean isSending;
            private MainActivity view;
            public EMMS(MainActivity view, int port, String ipAddress){
                try {

                    // Create Multicast socket
                    socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
                    usedPort = port;
                    // Set address to join
                    ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                    // join group
                    socket.joinGroup(ip);
                    System.out.println("Group Joined! ");
                    // create buffer
                    buffer = new byte[512];
                    isSending = false;
                    this.view = view;
                }//end of try
                catch (SocketException se){
                    System.out.println("Socket Exception : " + se); }
                catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("Exception : " + e); }
            }

            public void run(){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Incoming Message! ");

                    while (isSending == false) {
                        // Create and receive packet
                        System.out.println("1");

                    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,ip, usedPort);
                        System.out.println("2");
                        socket.receive(dp);
                        System.out.println("3");
                        String str = new String(dp.getData());
                        System.out.println("4");
                        String ipAddress = dp.getAddress().getHostAddress();
                        System.out.println("5");
                        // Create string array of components

                        String[] data = str.split("@@");
                        String senderName= data[2];
                        String sourceIP= ipAddress;
                        String typeOfEmergency=data[3];
                        String condition=data[0];
                        String instruction=data[1];
                        System.out.println("Incoming Message! ");
                        System.out.println(
                                "Sender: " + senderName + "\n" +
                                        "Source IP: " + sourceIP + "\n" +
                                        "Emergency Type: " + typeOfEmergency + "\n" +
                                        "Condition: " + condition + "\n" +
                                        "Instruction: " + instruction
                        );

                        // Create popup window
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view).create(); //Read Update
                        alertDialog.setTitle("ALERT");
                        alertDialog.setMessage(
                                "Sender: " + senderName + "\n" +
                                "Source IP: " + sourceIP + "\n" +
                                "Emergency Type: " + typeOfEmergency + "\n" +
                                "Condition: " + condition + "\n" +
                                "Instruction: " + instruction
                        );

                        alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!
                    }
                }//end of try
                catch (SocketException se){
                    System.out.println("Socket Exception : " + se); }
                catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("Exception : " + e); }


            }
            public void disconnect() throws IOException{
                socket.leaveGroup(ip);
            }
```

Comment: You don't need to put the IP address and port into a `DatagramPacket` you're about to receive into. `String str = new String(dp.getData())` should be `String str = new String(dp.getData(), dp.getOffset(), dp.getLength())`.

Comment: I made those changes, but it is still dying at '                        socket.receive(dp);'